# Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local commutative ring. And suppose that $m^{n} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local commutative ring. And suppose that $m^{n} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Then I want to show that $m/m^2$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field $R/m$. I am told that it follows from Nakayama’s Lemma, but I don't seem why.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Nakayama's lemma, nor the assumption that $\mathfrak m$ is nilpotent. Notice that

$$\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2 = \mathfrak m \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m.$$

Since $\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated over $R$, it follows that $\mathfrak m \otimes_R R/\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated over $R/\mathfrak m$ (by the images of a set of generators of $\mathfrak m$).

Comment: I am sure I'm missing something really obvious. But how would one show that $x\otimes 1_{r/\mathfrak{m}} = 0$ implies $x \in \mathfrak{m^2}$?

Comment: @user93826 In general, for any $R$, any ideal $I$ and any $R$-module $M$, we have $M/IM = M \otimes_R R/I$.

Comment: Okay thank you. Could you finally elaborate on your final sentence please? 'Since m is finitely generated over R, it follows that m⊗RR/m is finitely generated over R/m (by the images of a set of generators of m).'

Comment: @user93826 In general, if $B$ is an $A$-algebra and $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module, then $M\otimes_A B$ is a finitely-generated $B$-module. To see it, choose a surjection $A^n \to M$ and tensor it with $B$, using the fact that the tensor product preserves surjections.

Answer (score 2):

The $R$-module $m/m^2$ is finitely generated. Since $m$ annihilates it, it becomes a module over $R/m$ with the same set of generators.